# Writing a | delimited file in python without a trailing |

Tags: python, python-behave

I am trying to write a simple .DAT file in Python as part of my Behave test. 
The system needs a file containing a string of values each separated by a `|`. However, there should be no "|" after the last value

Currently I list the values to be written in my behave step as a table. Given a table of values:

```
|value|
|aa    |
|bb    |
|cc    |
|dd    |
```

I then call my generate file method from in the step

```
@given("a table of values")
def step_impl(context):
file_path = os.path.join("temp", "file_name.DAT")
generate_test_file(context.table, file_path)
```

My method is then

```
def generate_test_file(self, table, location):
    with open(location, "w") as test_file:
        for row in table:
            test_file.write(f"{row['value']}")
```

This generates a file of the following

```
aa|bb|cc|dd|
```

Compared to the file I want which is

```
aa|bb|cc|dd
```

Is there an easier way of achieving the flexibility above (being able to define data simply in the step) while generating the file I need?

Comment: `"|".join(table)` Edit: or rather: `"|".join(row['value'] for row in table)`?

Comment: this is splitting each of the rows up for some reason so getting a|a|b|b|c|c|d|d no trailing | though

Answer (score 0):

I would use the python [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and set the delimiter to be "**|**".  It will do a lot of the tedious output work for you.

Comment: will this not auto generate a CSV file, which is not what I want, it specifically has to be a .DAT file to replicate the file we will be recieving from the customer

Comment: You can use the csv module to write files with any name, field separators, delimiters, line endings that you want.  You can also use it to write to stdout or into stringsio too.